# SQL multiple unique columns

Tags: sql, constraints, unique

Is it possible to use unique on multiple columns?

like:

```
 user_vote user_id 
 ------------------
      1         1
      1         2
      2         1
```

both unique

This must be possible

But:

```
  user_vote user_id
     1         2
     1         2
```

This must not be possible

Comment: Just define an **UNIQUE CONSTRAINT** over both columns .... should be possible in any database that support SQL as it's query language...

Comment: yes you can in any database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a unique constraint on the column's combination:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD CONSTRAINT my_table_uq UNIQUE (user_vote, user_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

## MySQL / SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access:

```
 CREATE TABLE uservotetable
 (
   user_vote int NOT NULL,
   user_id int NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT uservote UNIQUE (user_vote ,user_id)
  );
```

and if you created your table before ..then you can use  *ALTER*

```
  ALTER TABLE uservotetable
  ADD CONSTRAINT uservote UNIQUE (user_vote ,user_id)
```

this can be useful for you [sql_unique](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a composite unique constraint.

SQL Server,
One way to do that in SQL Server is by adding UNIQUE `INDEX`

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD UNIQUE INDEX (User_Vote, User_Id);
```

In Oracle,

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_1 UNIQUE (User_Vote, User_Id)
```